# How to add class in thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf

I am trying to add css in thymeleaf but am getting internal server error.

```
<span th:style="'content:('\ +${{user.getUserIcon()}}+')'"></span>
```

How to add css class in thymeleaf?for example I have this class in css I have to display it using thymeleaf

```
.content .users{
content:"\42";
color:#fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got Solution

```
<span th:class="${{user.getUserIcon()}}"></span>
```

Comment: Can be simplified to `<span th:class="${user.userIcon}"></span>`